# Apache Auth config settings override auth headers issued from PHP

Tags: php, apache, http-headers, authorization

I am issuing a 401 header and a WWW-Authenticate header with a custom value "Application" from PHP. The custom value prevents a browser from loading the Apache authorization popup window, as it would if the WWW-Authenticate header were set to "Basic". This is the desired behavior for my application as the application handles authentication. This all works well and seems to follow the intent of the 401 status code, better than issuing a 403 header.

The problem arises when I run this on a server that already has Apache auth settings in the Apache config.The 401 header causes Apache to send the WWW-Authenticate method indicated in the Apache config rather than the WWW-Authenticate header I issued from PHP. So the response header becomes "Basic" as in the Apache config rather than "Application" as issued from my application. This results in an infinite authorization loop and the Apache auth popup just keeps coming up.

My solution to this for now it to just issue a 403 header, but it doesn't seem right to do so. A 403 indicates that the request will never be granted, even if the user authenticates.

Should I just not be using 401 headers for application level logins? It seems like it's only intended for HTTP authentication. If not, is 403 really appropriate for this? I've looked all over the place and can't find a definitive standard.

Comment: I guess I am trying to apply status codes written for the http protocol to my application and it doesn't translate exactly. It doesn't seem like there are any valid http status codes for this. I suppose a 403 may really be correct, as far as HTTP protocol is concerned. "As long as you keep issuing this same request, I am going to keep denying it.". HTTP is stateless and doesn't know anything about my application's login scheme.

Answer (score 0):

There is an otion to [unset an Apache header](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) (which work differently from setting the headers in PHP).

So you could try adding to .htaccess to remove the header for PHP files.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
Header unset WWW-Authenticate
</FilesMatch>
```